# React - Handle modification of cell inside state's array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, fixed-data-table

I'm creating my implementation of `fixed-data-table-2` (npm) where an edit button changes cells to input's, which may be edited and then saved (post).

[image]

But there's a major problem...
It's too slow the typing, because I'm updating the entire array (in state) every single time that `onChange` is triggered on the cell.

> Event Handler (Table)

```
import reactUpdate from "react/lib/update";
onChangeEditableCell(field, rowIndex, newValue) {
    const data = reactUpdate(this.state.data, {[rowIndex]: {[field]: {$set: newValue}}})
    this.setState({data : data});
}
```

> Event Handler (Cell)

```
onChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newValue = e.target.value;
    this.props.onHandleInput(this.props.field, this.props.rowIndex, newValue);
}

render() {
    const {rowIndex, field, data, editMode, onHandleInput, ...props} = this.props;

    return (
        <Cell {...props}>
            {editMode ? <input onChange={this.onChange} className="text-cell-edit" type="text" value={this.getCell()} /> : data[rowIndex][field]}
        </Cell>
    );
}
```

This is obviously a bad idea... How may I achieve the same but performance-wise?

**Note**

`onHandleInput` (cell's prop) is `onChangeEditableCell` (table's function)

**PS**

I need the `data` array to post the entire object when the user hits `Save`

Comment: Maybe I'm not following, but instead of modifying the state directly during "edit mode", why don't you modify a copy of the state and, when the user hits "save," just replace the whole object - or deep merge the two states?

Comment: Is it a good practice to create variables outside state? If that's the case, I'm going to search how to do it. It seems a better idea.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure - but it also seems excessive (and "dangerous") to stream changes to state and forcing unnecessary component re-rendering on every keystroke.

Comment: Yeah table-level state shouldn't change on every keypress. That kind of thing should live at the cell-level state. Then only when the save button is pressed should the table-level state update.

Comment: I tought about that, but I'm always articles about "dumb" and "stateless" components that I try to do almost always. But about the "cell-level" state, how would I update the Table's state when the `Save` is hited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do in this situation is make the cell have its own state, that updates with each keypress. Then update the table-level state with the `onblur` event, which fires after the input loses focus.

Individual inputs are, in my opinion, a good exception to the general practice of pulling state upward.

Comment: Well, I tried it and it works pretty well. I'll wait to see if someone comes with a better idea. But this suits well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some timeout:

```
onChange(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const newValue = e.target.value;
  if (this.timeout) {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    this.timeout = 0;
  }
  this.timeout = setTimeout(()=> {
    this.props.onHandleInput(this.props.field, this.props.rowIndex, newValue);
  }, 1000);

}
```